# Given two conditions find the normal vector for Stokes theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Calculate the work done by the force field $F=(z,y^2,-x)$ on a particle moving on the intersection between $y=z^2$ and $x^2+z^2=1$.

Parameterization seemed annoying and would only lead to very long calculations so I tried using stokes theorem:

$curl(F)=(0,2,0)$
$\int \int curl(F)\cdot \vec{N}dS=\int \int (0,2,0) \cdot \vec{n}dxdz$

The problem here is that I dont really have any idea how I am supposed to calculate $\vec{n}$. Normally i use $(-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}, 1)$ or $|{r}'_u \times {r}'_v|$ but here I dont have any clear function to use any formula on.

Comment: Try to draw, it should help; but I don't know if you can get away with not parameterizing it. If the surface weren't curved, you might have been able to, but in this case I don't think you can

Comment: Stokes' theorem applies on a surface and its boundary. So the first step would be to choose a surface which has that curve as its boundary. (There are many possible, but two obvious choices.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I. The hard way*** (seems not that hard)

For $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ we parametrize the intersection $\gamma$ of
the cylinder $x^2+z^2=1$ with the surface $y=z^2$ as
\begin{align}
x&=\cos\theta\,,&z&=-\sin\theta\,,&y&=\sin^2\theta\,.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\oint_\gamma F\cdot\,ds&=\int_0^{2\pi}\begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta\\\sin^4\theta\\-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta\\2\sin\theta\cos\theta\\-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\,d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta+2\sin^5\theta\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta\,d\theta\\
&=2\pi+\int_0^{2\pi}2\sin^5\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta\\
&=2\pi+2\int_0^0x^5\,dx=2\pi\,.
\end{align}

***II. Without any calculation*** (almost)

The curl of $F$ is $(0,2,0)$ which is

- divergence free
- points only in the $y$-direction, i.e, parallel to the boundary of the cylinder $x^2+z^2=1\,.$

By Stokes' theorem the integral $\oint_\gamma F\cdot\,ds$ equals the flux of
curl$\,F$ through a surface who's boundary is $\gamma\,.$ Since the integral of div curl$\,F(\equiv 0)$ over any volume that is the interior of the cylinder
capped on two sides by an arbitrary surface is zero we conclude now from Gauss' theorem that the flux of
curl $\,F$ through any surface capping the cylinder is the same. Instead of the complicated surface $y=z^2$ we can now choose the much simpler one $y=1$ and conclude that the flux is two times the area of that surface capping the cylinder:
$2\pi\,.$

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way, but parametrizing the curve is probably easier.

1. Using Stokes' theorem.

You first need to parametrize a surface whose boundary is the desired curve. A reasonable choice is to parametrize the part of the surface $y=z^2$ inside the solid cylinder $x^2+z^2\leq 1$. (Draw the intersection of the surfaces and you'll see why.) Setting $x=u$ and $z=v$ to get $y=v^2$, our parametrization is $\vec{r}(u,v) = (u,v^2,v)$ with domain $u^2+v^2\leq 1$. A simple computation yields

$$\vec{r}_u\times \vec{r}_v = (0,-1,2v)$$

So that

$$\int_C \vec{F}\cdot \vec{ds} = \iint_{u^2+v^2\leq 1} (0,2,0)\cdot(0,-1,2v) \ du dv = -2\iint_{u^2+v^2\leq 1}dudv = -2\pi$$

Note that 1) the orientation of the curve is ambiguous so I didn't consider the orientation here, and 2) if the integrand depended on $u$ or $v$, the integral would become more difficult to calculute and you're better off parametrizing the curve instead, but we got somewhat lucky here.

2. Parametrizing the curve directly.

We recognize in $x^2+z^2=1$ a circle of radius 1 (if $y$ were fixed), so a good choice is $x=\cos t, \ z=\sin t$, so that $y=\sin^2 t$, i.e. $
\vec{r}(t) = (\cos t, \sin^2 t, \sin t)$, with $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$ since we make 1 revolution around the cylinder. Then

$$\int_C \vec{F}\cdot \vec{ds} = \int_0^{2\pi} \vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))\cdot \vec{r}'(t)dt = \int_0^{2\pi} -\sin^2 t + 2\sin^5 t \cos t - \cos^2 t dt = -2\pi$$

Since $\cos^2t + \sin^2t = 1$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^5 t \cos t dt = 0$ (make a substitution $u = \sin t$).